# Memory leak Directory.GetFiles() VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks

I have a launcher utility I wrote that uses `Directory.GetFiles()` on a `Timer` to keep track of shortcuts in the start menu.

It has a memory leak, however. I'm not doing anything strange, so I don't understand why it's leaking... I leave the program open and after a few days, it's at 300mb. I used the CLR Profiler to try to locate the leak and it says the memory leakage is coming from `String` instances allocated by `Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
    IndexStartMenu()
    GC.Collect()
End Sub

Private Sub IndexStartMenu()

    Dim startMenu As IO.DirectoryInfo
    Dim shortcuts() As IO.FileInfo

    'Enumerate current user's start menu
    startMenu = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu))
    shortcuts = startMenu.GetFiles("*.lnk", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each lnk As IO.FileInfo In shortcuts
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dtApps.NewRow
        newRow("Application") = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lnk.FullName)
        newRow("Window") = "Launch"
        newRow("Hwnd") = ""
        newRow("IsShortcut") = True
        newRow("ShortcutPath") = lnk.FullName
        dtApps.LoadDataRow(newRow.ItemArray, LoadOption.Upsert)
        newRow = Nothing
    Next

    'Enumerate all users' start menu
    startMenu = New IO.DirectoryInfo(allUsersStartMenuPath)
    shortcuts = startMenu.GetFiles("*.lnk", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each lnk As IO.FileInfo In shortcuts
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dtApps.NewRow
        newRow("Application") = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lnk.FullName)
        newRow("Window") = "Launch"
        newRow("Hwnd") = ""
        newRow("IsShortcut") = True
        newRow("ShortcutPath") = lnk.FullName
        dtApps.LoadDataRow(newRow.ItemArray, LoadOption.Upsert)
        newRow = Nothing
    Next

    'Trying to fix memory usage
    startMenu = Nothing
    Array.Clear(shortcuts, 0, shortcuts.Length)
    shortcuts = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Be sure to deploy your Release build.  Debug builds for vb.net apps leak when they are run without a debugger attached.

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Wow, those few days flew by.  There isn't any way you can see that in 17 minutes.

Comment: lol, For testing purposes I changed the timer interval from 60,000ms to 20ms.

Comment: The string that you retrieve are being put in the datatable dtApps, which is not in the scope of the Sub. Maybe those are still referenced somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the method you posted, wouldn't the timer just fire every interval and add the contents of those directories repeatedly?  If dtApps is a DataTable field scoped to the class which persists for the duration of the application, you are just repeatedly adding the rows to the DataTable causing it to grow.  It is not a memory leak, but a natural event.  Check the row count of your dtApps.  My guess is that you are intending to only add new rows.

Also, you could improve the solution above and eliminate the need to poll the two directories based on a timer by employing a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).  The FileSystemWatcher will notify you by firing an event when there is a change to the file system.

Comment: Seems like the `LoadDataRow` with the `Upsert` parameter should take care of duplicates, however.

Comment: I believe this depends based on what the PK is for the DataTable. If there is not one specified, I think each call to LoadDataRow will result in an insert. LoadDataRow expects that the PK field(s) will be present in the data passed to it. Seeing the definition of the DataTable and/or the row count could would help answer the question if this is what might be happening.

Comment: Calvin is correct, that's why I have the upsert parameter specified. In CLR Profiler, the DataTable related memory is negligable. The problem is the strings created and appearently not garbage collected in the Directory.GetFiles() method...